# `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` compiler flag does not have an effect in Xcode for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to disable the exceptions in the compiler in Xcode 10.1 using `-fobjc-arc-exceptions`, but for some reason it does not take effect. My expectation is that the app won't stop running after throwing an exception. E.g.:

```
@try {
        [NSException raise:@"Testing" format:@"details: %@", self];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // do some stuff
    } @finally {
        // do some final stuff and continue as usual
    }
```

Based on http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions , `A program may be compiled with the option -fobjc-arc-exceptions in order to enable these, or with the option -fno-objc-arc-exceptions to explicitly disable them, with the last such argument “winning”.`

So I tried putting in `Build Phases` > `Compiler Sources` > all files, or `Build Settings` > `Other C Flags`, or `Other Linker Flags`..

My question is how to properly set this flag, and if my expectation is correct?
I do understand that exceptions should not be recovered from.

Comment: The `arc` in the flag name means that it turns off ARC-related exceptions. It doesn't turn off other exception support. (And if there were an option to turn off all support, it would also turn of the ability to parse `[NSException raise:…`, and your app wouldn't compile at all.)

Comment: thanks @arnt. so there is no way to let the app continue if it encounters a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` for example?

Comment: @arnt any comment on this? http://nerdyc.com/blog/2013/04/06/arc-doesnt-clean-up-after-exception/